# Hilt Error in Dynamic Feature component - Fragment does not implement GeneratedComponent or GeneratedComponentManager

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature

I'm developing an app with a dynamic features that saves user's favorites, and I'm using Hilt for injection.

But I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class com.rmaprojects.favorite.presentation.FavoriteFragment does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
    at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:62)
    at dagger.hilt.android.EntryPointAccessors.fromFragment(EntryPointAccessors.kt:66)
    at com.rmaprojects.favorite.presentation.FavoriteFragment.onAttach(FavoriteFragment.kt:38)
```

What I've done:

- Created @Component:

  ```
    @Component(
       dependencies = [FavoriteModuleDependencies::class]
    )
    interface FavoriteComponent {
    fun inject(fragment: FavoriteFragment)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun context(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder
        fun appDependencies(favoriteModuleDependencies: FavoriteModuleDependencies): Builder
        fun build(): FavoriteComponent
    }
  }
  ```
- Created Module for @EntryPoint:

  ```
  @EntryPoint
  @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
  interface FavoriteModuleDependencies {
    fun phonePediaUseCases(): PhonePediaUseCases
  }
  ```
- Applied component builder in the Fragment:

  ```
   class FavoriteFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_favorite) {

     @Inject
     lateinit var factory: ViewModelFactory

     private val viewModel: FavoriteViewModel by viewModels {
       factory
     }

     override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
         super.onAttach(context)
         DaggerFavoriteComponent.builder()
             .context(requireActivity().applicationContext)
             .appDependencies(
                 EntryPointAccessors.fromFragment(
                     this,
                     FavoriteModuleDependencies::class.java
                 )
             )
             .build()
             .inject(this)
      }
  ```

Any solution with this? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a minute ago by simply changing the EntryPointAccessors.fromFragment() into *.fromApplication() (Change requireContext() into requireActivity().application)